# Use arima.sim to simulate ARIMA 1,1,1 with drift in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-science, simulation, arima

I am trying to use ARIMA sim package to simulate an ARIMA simulation with a drift. My problem is that I cannot seem to get it to work.

I need to get something like this:

[image]

My code  is producing this though:

```
> mean(datatime)
[1] 15881.56
> sd(datatime)
[1] 8726.893
> length(datatime)
[1] 123
```

```
# The mean and variance from the original series

originalseriesmean = 15881.56
originalseriesvariance = 8726.893*8726.893
originalseriesn=123

# Simulation using arima.sim



ts.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(c(1,1,1)), n = 123, mean=190,sd=69.2863)

ts.plot(ts.sim)
```

[image: []
How do I add a drft term to this function to make it look like the simulation before?

Answer (score 1):

ARIMA process doesn't have any drift/trend by definition. Inspired by this answer on cross validated [arima with trend](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294600/how-can-i-simulate-with-arima-sim-drift-intercept-and-trend) and taking into consideration the value you want:

```
set.seed(123)
intercept <- 4500
b <- (32000 - intercept) / 123
x <- 1:123
y <- b * x + arima.sim(model=list(c(1, 0, 1)),
                    n = 123, mean=intercept, sd=2000)


> sd(y)
[1] 8020
> mean(y)
[1] 18370
```

The argument `mean` gives you the intercept of the process (where it starts), to obtain the variance you should detrend your process because the `mean` value and the `sd` values you give are with trend wherease to simulate such process you should decompose your process into noise + trend.